# Input variable name as raw string into request in python

Tags: python, loops, python-requests

I am kind of very new to python.
I tried to loop through an URL request via python and I want to change one variable each time it loops.

My code looks something like this:

```
codes = ["MCDNDF3","MCDNDF4"]

#count = 0
for x in codes:
    response = requests.get(url_part1 + str(codes) + url_part3, headers=headers)
    print(response.content)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.url)
```

I want to have the url change at every loop to like url_part1+code+url_part3 and then url_part1+NEXTcode+url_part3.

Sadly my request badly formats the string from the variable to "`%5B'MCDNDF3'%5D`".

It should get inserted as a raw string each loop. I don't know if I need url encoding as I don't have any special chars in the request. Just change code to MCDNDF3 and in the next request to MCDNDF4.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Notice you are never using `x` in the body of your loop. Do you know what a `for` loop actually does?

Comment: I just tried to make a simple loop and it worked like that. Is there any better solution?

Comment: The loop is fine; the point is you used the wrong variable (`codes` instead of `x`) in the body of the loop. That's either a simple typo or an indication of a profound misunderstanding of how loops work.

Comment: So I should say for code in codes instead of x ? If yes, why so? Sorry I am a beginner and that’s my first script I wrote.

Comment: `x` is set to a different value from `codes` in each iteration: `response = requests.get(url_part1 + str(x) + ...)`. I strongly recommend working through the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: It should iterate through every value every time it loops.. or am I misunderstanding something? codes is a list with parts of an URL which is changing constantly and I try to find the right one. that why I have a list of possible parts in the codes variable which should iterate at every loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `for` loop, the first line should be:

```
response = requests.get(url_part1 + x + url_part3, headers=headers)
```

This will work assuming `url_part1` and `url_part3` are regular strings. `x` is already a string, as your `codes` list (at least in your example) contains only strings. `%5B` and `%5D` are `[` and `]` URL-encoded, respectively. You got that error because you called `str()` on a single-membered list:

```
>>> str(["This is a string"])
"['This is a string']"
```

If `url_part1` and `url_part3` are raw strings, as you seem to indicate, please update your question to show how they are defined. Feel free to use `example.com` if you don't want to reveal your actual target URL. You should probably be calling `str()` on *them* before constructing the full URL.

Comment: Thanks that was an easy fix! My url variables are like this

`url_part1 = "https://example.com/Service/"
url_part3 = "/valid"`

Comment: @SabriLK okay, in that case you don't need raw strings at all.

Answer (score 0):

You’re putting the whole list in (codes) when you probably want x.